# Set auto-incrementing attribute in XML node

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to set an attribute in one of the nodes for my XML as below:

```
rank = 1
for photo in s:
  image = feed.createElement('Image')
  images.appendChild(image)
  image.setAttribute("rank", rank)
  p = feed.createTextNode(str(main_url+photo.display.url))
  image.appendChild(p)
  rank += 1
```

This however results in the error: `'int' object has no attribute 'replace'` in reference to the line: `image.setAttribute("rank", rank)`  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.setAttribute` method](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Element.setAttribute) expects a string, so you will have to convert it:

```
image.setAttribute("rank", str(rank))
```